# Finding the value of $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to find out the value of $n$, when equation is:
$(a - b) (a^{n+1} - b^{n+1}) = 0$

We have $a - b = 0\Rightarrow a = b$

and $(a^{n+1} - b^{n+1}) = 0\Rightarrow a^{n+1} = b^{n+1}$

Now how to solve for $n$.
It seems a simple question. But I don't know that simple trick.

Comment: If $a\ne b$ and $b\ne 0$, then $(\frac{a}{b})^{n+1}=1$, $n+1=0$

Comment: Oh Yes.. Thank you..

Comment: if $a=-b$ then you could take any odd $n$ ... literally :)

Comment: Easiest approach is that one told by Swapnil Tripathi.

Comment: for me easiest approach is $a=b$ then every $n$ works. I do not know what $n$ has to do with this problem :)

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ real numbers?  If they are allowed to be complex, the equation $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{n+1} = 1$ simply says that $a/b$ is an $(n+1)^\text{st}$ root of unity.

Comment: Also, this expression usually has exponents of n-1, not n+1, so the product gives $a^n-b^n$, not $a^{n+2}-b^{n+2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer expands on the answer given by Swapnil Tripathy in the comments.

We'll assume $a \neq b$ (otherwise, $n$ could be anything)
and $b \neq 0$ (otherwise, we have $a^{n+2} = 0$, so $a$ is 0 and $n$ can be anything.)

In this case, $a - b$ is not 0, so we must have $a^{n+1} - b^{n+1} = 0$,
or $a^{n+1} = b^{n+1}$,
hence $\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^{n+1} = 1$.

One possibility is that $a = -b$, and $n + 1$ is even.
In any other case, $\dfrac{a}{b} \neq \pm 1$,
so the only power which is 1 is $\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^0 = 1$;
hence $n = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

Venturing into the complex domain,
if $a/b$ is a complex
$m$-th root of unity,
then
$n = m-1$.